# Milliseconds passed since last minute in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I'm probably just tired and not thinking clearly, but can someone give a concise way of getting the number of milliseconds passed since the last minute using javascript?

Something like `Date.getSeconds()`, but that would return milliseconds.

Although I could just do `(Date.getSeconds()*1000) + Date.getMilliseconds()`, this just seems really awkward and like there has to be a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: `(Date.getSeconds()*1000) + Date.getMilliseconds()` **is** the most reasonable way.

Comment: There's a lot about the JavaScript `Date` implementation that is inelegant (partly modeled after Java's implementation).

Comment: If you have two dates, just subtracting one from the other gives you the difference in milliseconds. It's a little unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm just going for greater precision than seconds for an animation that I'm running.  It I set it to cycle once per minute, so I just needed the milliseconds passed during the current clock minute.  I used the 'awkward' method in my original post and as recommended by dystroy above.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about…

```
Date.now() % 60000
```

`Date.now` returns the current UNIX timestamp in ms.

---

To clarify what's happening there, the `%` operator is called *modulo* and what it does is that it gives you the remainder from dividing the first number by the other one.

An example can be:

```
20 % 7 === 6
13 % 7 === 6
 6 % 7 === 6
```

…because…

```
20 / 7 = 2 + 6 / 7
13 / 7 = 1 + 6 / 7
 6 / 7 = 0 + 6 / 7
```

(note the remainder `6`)

Comment: Nice, + 1. A brief explanation of modulus might be handy for future visitors. To the untrained eye that might look like voodoo.

Answer (score 6):

Depends what you're trying to do.

The difference between now and 1 minute ago in milliseconds should always be 60000 milliseconds. o_O

As Jan said `Date.now()` will return the current timestamp in milliseconds.

But it seems you might be looking for the getTime method, e.g.:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

```
// note the keyword "new" below
var date_instance = new Date();

// separate example in case you're managing Date()'s and not the method,
// who knows, just an example
var timestamp     = date_instance.getTime();

var minute_before_timestamp = function(ts){ 
  return ts - 60000;
};
console.log(minute_before_timestamp(timestamp));
console.log(minute_before_timestamp(date_instance.getTime()); // always same as above!

// or use the current time
console.log(minute_before_timestamp(Date.now()));
console.log(minute_before_timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

(another useful link: http://www.epochconverter.com/)